# Why Enumerable doesn't inherits from IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, enumerable

I'm very confused about this issue and can't understand it.In the `Enumerable` Documentation, I read this:

> that implement System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

and some methods like `Select()` return `IEnumerable<TSource>` that we can use from other methods like `Where()` after using that.for example:

```
names.Select(name => name).Where(name => name.Length > 3 );
```

but `Enumerable` doesn't inherit from `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't contain `Select()`,`Where()` and etc too...

have i wrong ?
or exists any reason for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Select(), Where() etc are "[extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)". They need to be defined "elsewhere" as an interface can't supply an implementation of methods.

You can recognize extension methods by the keyword "this" in the argument list. For instance:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
```

can be used as if it's a method on an `IEnumerable<TSource>` with one parameter: `Func<TSource, bool> predicate`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.but what about this sentence?

> that implement System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

According to this sentence,We have to define methods in the `IEnumerable<T>` interface and implement in the `Enumerable` class by inheritance.is it correct?

why preferred extension methods against inheritance?

Comment: Note that you're supposed to add a comment or edit your question, rather than creating a new answer to add new information or questions.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable came before `IEnumerable<T>`, which is a 2.0+ interface.

Answer (score 0):

"why preferred extension methods against inheritance?"

Enumerable is a static class that implements over 50 extension methods to IEnumerable. This lets you use all those extension methods on types that implement IEnumerable without forcing the programmers to implement all those methods for each collection type. If Enumerable were an interface instead of a static class, each collection type (such as List, Dictionary, Set, etc) would have its own implementation of these extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this is by casting the elements to their same type using `Cast<T>()` method, which returns and `IEnumerable<T>` version of the same elements.

```
DataTable dt = ...
dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where()...
```

`Rows` is of type `IEnumerable`, and after casting it becomes of type `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, which is supported by LINQ extension methods.